# __has_trivial_copy behaves differently in clang and gcc. Who's right?

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::is_trivially_copyable` is still not supported in either of those two compilers (at least as far as gcc 4.6). But both provide `__has_trivial_copy` directives that do pretty good job.
Except when it comes to deleted copy constructors.

```
struct A { A(A const&) =delete; };
```

`__has_trivial_copy(A)` returns 1 in clang and 0 in gcc.

I was digging in the standard and could not find a clause that says whether the class is still considered trivially copyable when the copy constructor is deleted.

Who's right?

My inclination is to believe that gcc is right, because `struct A` is not copyable at all, let alone trivially copyable. Also, there's a wide-spread consensus, that a deleted copy constructor can be seen as a privately declared, but not defined constructor, in which case gcc would still be right.

On the other hand, the standard in section 9/6 describes trivial-copyability in terms of not having any non-trivial operations. I guess if you read the standard as written, clang may be right.

Comment: What is the specification of `__has_trivial_copy(type)`?? `A` is certainly trivially copyable (and there is no problem `memcpy`ing an instance of it). There are certainly some `std::is_foobar` type traits that "contradict" the core language foobary specification, but `__has_trivial_copy` is not defined in the C++ Standard.

Comment: From the gcc docs: __has_trivial_copy (type)
If __is_pod (type) is true or type is a reference type then the trait is true, else if type is a cv class or union type with a trivial copy constructor ([class.copy]) then the trait is true, else it is false. Requires: type shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array of unknown bound.

Comment: Never use the compiler hooks directly, you're just *asking* for trouble. Just use `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

Comment: I'm afraid that when both of these compilers introduce std::is_trivially_copyable, they'll simply use the current mechanism, which is incompatible. I get the point that A is memcopyable though.

Comment: From the looks of gcc docs, `__has_trivial_copy` sounds more closely related to `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible` than `std::is_trivially_copyable`.  But don't worry, the g++ library guys are smarter than to just use the old extension and assume it's right.

Comment: Here's another interesting fact: 'struct trivial{ trivial() {} }; __has_trivial_copy(trivial); __has_trivial_copy(trivial[1]);' In clang the first one returns 1, the second one returns zero. Both return one in gcc. I guess this looks like a clang bug where arrays of trivial types that have user-defined default constructor are not considered to be trivial

Comment: @AndyVenikov note that in the Standard, array types are not *DefaultConstructible*, but still `std::is_default_constructible` must yield `true`. This gross thing was reported to LWG issue list maintainers by myself some weeks ago.

Answer (score 5):

libc++, clang's native library, supports `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>` and, indeed, pretends on your example that the type is trivially copyable although it is clearly not trivially copyable. I think, 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 12 defines the deleted constructor as non-trivial:

> A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided ...

The deleted declaration is clearly user-provided. When I say "clearly" here I mean that I can't immediately back it up by the standard that declaring a function as deleted counts as user-provided...

Further investigation reveals that 8.4.2 [dcl.fct.def.default] paragraph 4 (thanks to Jesse Good for providing the reference) makes a deleted function non-user-provided:

> ... A special member function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. ...

Thus, a class with a deleted copy constructor is indeed trivially copyable if there is no other reason to make non-trivially copyable (but none of those applies to the type `A` in the question. That's a bit weird: type type cannot be copied using its copy constructor but it *can* be copied using `std::memcpy()`! I'm not sure if this is really intentional.

Comment: From [8.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions]: `A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or
deleted on its first declaration.`. So, it is not user-provided.

Comment: However, the quote you mention says `is user-provided or deleted` in my copy, and since it is deleted it is not trivially copyable.

Comment: @JesseGood: Actually, the document I'm staring at doesn't say anything about "deleted" in this section! Maybe I should actually get the standard and this could also be the exact source of the confusion!

Comment: The actual standard doesn't mention `deleted` here either.

Comment: @JesseGood: Which document are you looking at? The standard definitely doesn't state "or deleted" in 12.8 paragraph 12!

Comment: My draft was not up to date. See [defect report 1135](www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1135).

Comment: That's a mess! I think this needs to be brought up the C++ standardization committee.

Comment: @DietmarKühl That page belongs to and is provided by the C++ standardization committee.  And they already acted on it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl : The status of that DR is FDIS, which means it made it into C++11 proper.

Comment: I know that this is the CWG working list: I'm frequently attending the meetings and working on these lists! ;) The point is: this change seems to have introduced a rather weird situation: a type which cannot be copied using its copy constructor but which can be copied using `std::memcpy()`!

Comment: @Dietmar : Ah, I was wondering why you seemed confused – I know of your presence at the meetings. :-] I agree with your assessment, things seem quite inconsistent at this point.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The "this needs to be brought up" makes a lot more sense after noticing you edited your answer.

Comment: That was an explicit change in the Standard from earlier drafts and other parts of the Standard (for example value-initialization) was changed so that text that previously referred to a constructor being "trivial" then refered to "trivial and not deleted". The same is true for inaccessible default ctors (accessibility is not an inherent property of functions, so I too think *it* should not influence triviality IMHO). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1507 .

Comment: Some other things are still allowed. For example having `struct A { ~A() = delete; };` then in a file that does not have A's definition, `void f(A *a) { delete a; };` is well-formed *and well-defined*. But if you include A's header, it becomes *ill-formed*. The delete-of-incomplete-class rule was not changed to respect deleted or inaccessible destructors (no pun intended). My committee contact people said this isn't worth fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct or incorrect, since both are using extensions.

**Warning**: This answer was based on words which were in C++11 draft N3242, but are not in the final Standard.  So it's not especially good.  Leaving it up for comparison and discussion.

For what it seems you meant to ask: `std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value` (and also `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<A>::value`) must be `false`.

12.8 paragraph 13:

> A copy/move constructor for class `X` is trivial if it is neither user-provided nor deleted and if....

And just to be complete,

9 paragraph 6:

> A *trivially copyable class* is a class that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
> - has a trivial destructor (12.4).

3.9 paragraph 9:

> Scalar types, trivially copyable class types (Clause 9), arrays of such types, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *trivially copyable types*.

20.9.4.3 Table 49:

> Template: `template <class T> struct is_trivially_copyable;`
>
> Condition: `T` is a trivially copyable type (3.9)

Comment: What version of the document are you using? I'm looking at the final draft, and under 12.8/12 (not 12.8/26 nor under 12.8/2 which was the original version before the edit) it says: *A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided and if...*. Nothing about deleted.

Comment: And whoops, that citation in N3242 should in fact be paragraph 13.  (26 is for assignments. No clue where 2 came from. I seem to be having trouble with numbers tonight.)

Comment: Well, I'm looking at 3290. So I guess my document beats your document :) It looks like "nor deleted" was taken out