# ‘is_trivially_copyable’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

My gcc version is 4.8.3 20140624. I can use `is_pod`, `is_trivial`, `is_standard_layout`, but fail when trying `is_trivially_copyable`, `is_constructible` and `is_default_constructible`, maybe more. The error message is `'xxx' is not a member of 'std'`.

What's the problem here? Are they even supported by the current GCC? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of them are not implemented. If we look at [libstdc++'s c++11 status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011):

**Type properties** are listed as **partially implemented**.

They list as missing:

- is_trivially_copyable
- is_trivially_constructible
- is_trivially_default_constructible,
- is_trivially_copy_constructible
- is_trivially_move_constructible
- is_trivially_assignable
- is_trivially_default_assignable
- is_trivially_copy_assignable
- is_trivially_move_assignable

#### That being said:

`is_constructible` and `is_default_constructible` should be available. I can use them successfully in GCC 4.8.2.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<int>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_default_constructible<int>::value << "\n";
}
```

```
[11:47am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++ -std=c++11 foo.cc
[11:47am][wlynch@apple /tmp] ./a.out 
1
1
```

Comment: @JonathanWakely I changed up the wording a bit. If you have the list for 4.8.3 (or you know that it hasn't changed), feel free to fix this answer with them. Otherwise, I'll just leave the documented list for 4.9.1.

Comment: The list for 4.8.3 is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 and the missing traits in that table are accurate, but the rest of the table might be less accurate than the latest version of the table ... I'm not sure when I went through and tried to make it complete. The list you originally linked to is for the subversion trunk, _not_ 4.9.1, that's at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Answer (score 21):

As others mention, GCC versions < 5 do not support `std::is_trivially_copyable` from the C++11 standard.

Here is a hack to somewhat work around this limitation:

```
// workaround missing "is_trivially_copyable" in g++ < 5.0
#if __GNUG__ && __GNUC__ < 5
#define IS_TRIVIALLY_COPYABLE(T) __has_trivial_copy(T)
#else
#define IS_TRIVIALLY_COPYABLE(T) std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value
#endif
```

For common cases, this hack might be enough to get your code working. Beware, however, [subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754886/has-trivial-copy-behaves-differently-in-clang-and-gcc-whos-right) between GCC's [`__has_trivial_copy`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Type-Traits.html#:%7E:text=bound.-,__has_trivial_copy,-(type)) and `std::is_trivially_copyable`. Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 8):

GCC (libstdc++ in this case) implements several type-trait **with different, non-standard names** as per an *earlier* version of the standardization proposal for type traits. Specifically:

```
std::has_trivial_copy_constructor<int>::value
```

This only provides part of the information that a full implementation of [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) would provide, as having a trivial copy constructor is necessary but not sufficient for a [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) type.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/938f21984059a342)

Comment: Being `TriviallyCopyable` does not require having a trivial copy constructor.

Comment: I don't usually vote down, but this information can lead to confusion. If you edit it I will remove the down vote.

Comment: @GermánDiago I hopefully improved the answer enough, feel free to edit if you still think something is missing/wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Just FYI, these traits are now implemented and will ship in GCC 5.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the C++ 2011 implementation of GCC seems to not support ‘is_trivially_copyable’. See [point 20.9.4.3 of the status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014)

You can try to install Clang3.4 and compile with option -std=c++1y

Comment: This is a property of the c++ standard library, not the compiler. So libstdc++ vs libc++, not gcc vs clang.